# Need help with tables (beginner)

Tags: tables

I'd like to convert this table (cf picture) in LaTeX but I can't find on google how to properly create new cases. Can anyone help me please?
[image: My table written in Google Docs]

Comment: Do you mean the cells with the small arrows? You can do that with a custom `itemize` environment.

Comment: Oh no I meant how to create the cells themselves. And how to change line within a same cell too I can't manage to create such table

Comment: You have to use  a fixed width column type (usually `p` \ or `X` from package `tabularx` if you want the table to have a total width that is prescribed). To create a new line, either a blank line in the cell code, or `newline`. Didn't you read an introduction to LaTeX?

Comment: You can start from: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
First column & Second column\\
\hline
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504984/need-help-with-tables-beginner} 
& Content of the cell: \newline Some text in the second cell. Some text in the second cell. Some text in the second cell. Some text in the second cell.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}`

Comment: Oh thanks that's exactly what I was looking for! My work is done thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code which reproduces; more or less faithfully, the first two rows. I only replaced the quotes with french quotes since your  example is in French:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, stmaryrd}
\usepackage{babel}
\frenchsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{tabularx, caption}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
 \usepackage{xurl}
 \def\UrlFont{\sf}
 \usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=CornflowerBlue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

 \begin{document} 

 \begin{table}[!ht]
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, label =$\shortrightarrow$, topsep=0pt, after=\leavevmode\vskip\dimexpr-\baselineskip + \partopsep}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\captionsetup{skip=6pt, font=sf, labelfont=sf}
     \centering\sffamily
     \caption{A beginner’s table}\label{beg}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|>{\compress\arraybackslash}X|}
   \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Site} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Commentaires} \\[0.5ex]
    \hline
   \url{http://egon.cheme. cmu. edu/docs/cran/emarch07.pdf} & %
   \begin{itemize}
        \item Évoque les contraintes liées à la planification des portiques de quai: \newline ex. : temps, coût, espace, main d’œuvre %
        \item Optimisation théorique des chemins (pour maximiser le temps d’utilisation de chacune des grues couplées) %
        \item Notion de « représentation d’état » ?
   \end{itemize}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
   \end{table}

     \end{document}
```

[image]